# different controllers and methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a beginner and there is something I'm a bit confused with.

I have a website that is similar to Metacritic for TV Shows, my two tables are  shows and reviews.

There is my show (as in tv show) controller

```
  def show
    @show = Show.find(params[:id])
    @reviews = @show.reviews.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @ratings = @show.reviews.average("rating")


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @show }

    end
  end
```

and my show view

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>
<p>
  <%= @show.name %> (  <%= @show.year %>
)
</p>


<p>
  <b>Synopsys:</b>
  <%= @show.synopsys %>
</p>
<p>
  <b>Note:</b>
  <%= @ratings %>
</p>
<%= image_tag @show.avatar.url %>

      </h1>

    </section>
    <section>
    </section>
  </aside>

<div class="span8">
<% if @show.reviews.any? %>
<h3>Reviews (<%= @show.reviews.count %>)</h3>


<ol class="reviews">
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>

   <%= review.content %> <br> <%= review.source %> | <b><%= review.rating %> </b><br><br>
<br><br>
<% end %>
</ol>

<%= will_paginate @reviews %>
```

Now, I'm trying to do a similar thing on my home view (controller home). I want to add all the shows to the database and their overall ratings. The issue if that when I copy the content of my show controller to my home controller, review is undefined and I don't understand why.
Anyone can help ?

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @shows = Show.all
    @ratings = @show.reviews.average("rating")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @show }

    end

      def about
    end


      def contact
    end
  end
  end
```

Comment: In my home I want to add all the shows and their overall ratings so I thought I could simply do <% @shows.each do |show| %> show.name show content show.rating but the home controller doesn't seem to understand the table relationship like the other does.

Comment: Is your home controller what the root of the site is routed to? If so, it might be cleaner (less code duplication) to put `root :to => 'shows#index'` in your routes.rb -- the ShowController should be dealing with Shows, not the HomeController

Comment: That's a good point, thank you.
Can you explain why the homecontroller wont respond to review ?

Comment: I added home controller
I want to call show.name show.year (those work) and the rating (that doesn't)

Comment: Is it because `rating` is a property of a show's review, rather than a show? If that's the case, you would need to do `show.review.rating`. It's difficult to answer, though; 'it doesn't work' doesn't help much.

Comment: It says undefined method for review, I'll try working at it a bit more. Thanks for your help @hdgarrood